# Input fields "inherits" value from past input fields when changing state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple component that has a title and two input fields

```
<h2>Login</h2>
<input type='text' id="login-username" placeholder="Username"></input>
<input type='password' id="login-password" placeholder="Password"></input>
<button className="btn btn-success" id="login-button">Login</button>
```

and then i have a state that removes and input field (password) and adds another one

```
<h2>Login</h2>
<input type='text' id="login-username" placeholder="Username"></input>
<input type='password' id="login-code" placeholder="Code"></input>
<button className="btn btn-success" id="login-button">Login</button>
```

```
import '../css/Login.css';

import GenericWindow from "../components/GenericWindow";
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { store } from 'react-notifications-component';


class Login extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        document.title = "Login"
        this.state = {
            view:'login'
        }
    }

    render(){
        if (this.state.view == "login"){

            return(
                <GenericWindow>
                <h2>Login</h2>
               <input type='text' id="login-username" placeholder="Username"></input>
               <input type='password' id="login-password" placeholder="Password"></input>
               <a onClick={
                            () => {
                                this.setState({view:"login-code"})
                            }
                        }>Login with code</a>
               <button className="btn btn-success" id="login-button">Login</button>

            </GenericWindow>
        )
        }else{
            return(
                    <h2>Login</h2>
                    <input type='text' id="login-username" placeholder="Username"></input>
                    <input type='password' id="login-code" placeholder="Code"></input>
                    
                    <button className="btn btn-success" id="login-button">Login</button>
                    </GenericWindow>
                )
        }
    }
}


export default Login;
```

I change the states using this.SetState, the problem is that when i change the state from the first one to the second one, if the password field has any content the code field has it when i change the state. Im currently learning reactjs so i might be doing this completly wrong and states are not the way to go. Anyways,  how can i prevent this behaviour? Or if i should not be using state for this what should i be using?

Comment: If you don't show the code, we can't spot the mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behavior due to [React's reconciliation algorithm](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html). While you think of it as removing one input and adding another one, what React sees is that there's still an input field, just with changed `id` and `placeholder` attributes. It doesn't unmount the element and mount a new one - it's just a change in props. This is reflected in the DOM - React keeps the *same* input element and only changes its attribute values.

To avoid this, you can give them different `key`s.